# Finding fixed points of an equation when the derivative is not defined

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

> For a dynamical system governed by the equation $f(x) = \mathrm{d}y/\mathrm{d}x = 2(1-x^2)^{1/2}$. Find stable and unstable fixed points.

The fixed points for the above equation are $+1$ and $-1$. I took the derivative of given equation and set it equal to zero.
If $f'(x)<0$, it's a stable point and if $f'(x)>0$, it's an unstable point.
The derivative is
$$\frac{-2x}{(1-x^2)^{1/2}}$$
Now if I plug $x=1$ or $x=-1$, it's not defined. How do I find the stability of fixed points in this case?

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're looking for. Is the unknown function $y(x)$? Then what does $f(x)$ have to do with anything? Or is the system $\dot x = f(x)$? Then what does $y$ have to do with it? (Or is it a discrete system $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$? Not likely, since $f(0)=2$ goes outside the interval where $f$ is defined.)

Answer (score 1):

If what you mean is that the system is $dx/dt=f(x)$, then just draw the phase portrait on the interval $[-1,1]$, using that $dx/dt > 0$ for $-1<x<1$.

Comment: I am not able to understand how we conclude about the stability of the fixed points by obtaining $dx/dt>0$?

Comment: @BAYMAX: Well, what happens if you perturb one of the equilibria $\pm 1$ a little, by moving into the open interval $(-1,1)$? Where does the point go, as $t \to +\infty$, if it can only move to the right? (Since the system is only defined on $[-1,1]$, it's not meaningful to talk about perturbing the equilibria out of this interval.)

Comment: Yes, thanks but that is exactly what i want to see, I want to write $x(1-\epsilon)$ but how could i?, i dont know the analytical solution? how should i proceed?

Comment: but how could i?, i dont know the analytical solution? how should i proceed?, but since $dx/dt>0$ so perturbation from 1 on the right side will definitely push the trajectory to the right, so I think the trajectory moves away from $x=-1$ hinting me unstable but now if we similar analysis to $x=1$, it will push the trajectory to the left since $dx/dt>0$, so $x$ value must increase as $t$ increases, that is it pushes the x to left so kind of repelling from $x=1$, so I think both $x=1,-1$ are unstable???

Comment: @BAYMAX: You don't need the analytical solution, that's the whole point of looking at the phase portrait instead. Anyway, your resoning is on the right track, except that when you perturb $x=+1$ towards the left, into the interval $(-1,1)$, the point will be pushed *back* towards the right, back to the equilibrium where you started. So $x=+1$ is stable.

Comment: nice! but if we start near to $x=1$ on the left(since it cannot be on the right of 1, violating domain), then if the next iterate will rightwards then $x$ value is decreasing (evident from the curve here - downward parabola), now $x$ cannot decrease as $dx/dt>0$, please help?

Comment: here - https://www.desmos.com/calculator/q5xhecndvy

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean... If you're talking about iterates, then you're referring to a discrete-time dynamical system $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$. But I clearly stated in my answer that I'm talking about the continuous-time case $dx/dt=f(x)$. (It's far from clear what was meant in the original question, but as my comment there said, it's not likely to be a discrete-time system since $f(0)$ goes outside of the domain.)

Comment: And $f(x)$ being decreasing is not a problem, it just means that $x(t)$ will increase more slowly (but it will still increase, since $f(x)>0$).

Comment: Chat extended, sorry, can Iinvite you to [Dynamical Systems chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55403/dynamical-systems-and-chaos-theory), to discuss a bit about the analysis near $x=1$?

Comment: I'm not a chat person, keep the comments here please.

Comment: Sorry, when we are near $x=1$, and we check how the dynamics is evolving after this perturbation? we say suppose $x$ goes towards right side of the Initial condition, then due to the downward parabola, $x$ value decreased, so my question is how here still $dx/dt>0$ ?

Comment: @BAYMAX: No no no, it's not $x$ that's decreasing. What's decreasing is the value $f(x)$ which describes the **velocity** $dx/dt$. The $x$ value is still increasing, only more slowly (as I already wrote in a previous comment). Just to be clear, do you understand that I'm talking about a differential equation $dx/dt=f(x)$ and **not** a discrete-time system?

Comment: Got it!!, thanks!! i was a bit confused

Comment: @BAYMAX: Great!