# A question about stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, fixed-points

A dynamical system is governed by the equation $\frac{dx}{dt}=2\sqrt{1-x^2}$, $|x|\leq 1$. Then By equating $\frac{dx}{dt}$ to $0$ we get $1,-1$ are the fixed points. But how to check their stability? We can not check values of $\frac{dx}{dt}$ left to $-1$ and right to $1$.

Comment: You might want to declare that $-1$ is unstable and $1$ is stable since $x_0=-1+\epsilon$ with $\epsilon>0$ and small does not yield $x(t)-(-1)\to0$ while $x_0=1-\epsilon$ with $\epsilon>0$ and small yields $x(t)-1\to0$.

Comment: would you please explain a bit

Comment: would you please explain a bit

Comment: I did. (Gaear Grimsrud, in *Fargo*)..

Comment: @Anupam you can see this [Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1731963/finding-fixed-points-of-an-equation-when-the-derivative-is-not-defined/1732020?noredirect=1#comment6047419_1732020), some extensive discussion with Hans Lundmark is carried out, the main thing is $dx/dt $ is increasing over $[-1,1]$ and analysing [the phase portrait](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/q5xhecndvy), any other query do let me know and just to state [Dynamical Systems Chaos theory chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55403/dynamical-systems-and-chaos-theory), hope this helps!